# IntelliJ CE Access to remote Linux Filesystem Folders not shown in Project Explorer

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to open a web project containing .hmlt and .css files which is stored in the public_html folder of a Linux pc running apache server with an IntelliJ installation on a windows machine.

I created a "static web" project with intelliJ in the Network Folder and have the following problem:

`KarmaTest1` is the project main folder. I can see all files in this folder but not the sub folders. In the Navigation Bar I can see and access all subfolders and containing files.

[image]

How can i Display the subfolders of the project main Folder `karmaTest1` in the project explorer

Comment: What happens if you access the exact same address in windows explorer? And, have you tried creating a mapping to this folder and opening it via the mapping?

Comment: I created a Z: Map Drive and it works